# Auto wire a ViewModel inside a folder

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-6

I am using Prism unity as dependency injector in my WPF project. My ViewModels are located in a folder. Can you tell me if there is a way to autowire these ViewModels to my view ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Define *autowire* ...

Comment: xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"

Comment: If you have a folder name which is not named ViewModels then this should be useful http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/ read at the paragraph "Change those Nasty Conventions" and look at ViewModelLocationProvider.